# Prevent Network Drive Access from FolderBrowseDialog VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

I am using the FolderBrowseDialog in my Vb,Net Windows Form to ask the user to locate where a specific file is on their computer but I only want to allow local drives and not Network Drives.

Does anyone know of a way to prevent Network Drives from showing in the FolderBrowseDialog or stop them from been selected.

Comment: Do you mean mapped network drives? You can pass the FBD SelectedPath to DriveInfo: `var dInfo = new DriveInfo(fbd.SelectedPath); if (dInfo.DriveType == DriveType.Network) { ... }`. Show a warning and present the dialog again.

Comment: When trying that code, it threw an exception.  {"Object must be a root directory (""C:\"") or a drive letter (""C"")."} System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

Comment: Well, I posted it in C# for some reason. You may not have adapt it to VB.Net (and your existing code) as it should be: `Using fbd As New FolderBrowserDialog() fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer If fbd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then dim dInfo as new DriveInfo(fbd.SelectedPath) if dInfo.DriveType = DriveType.Network then [...] End If End If End Using`

Comment: Thank You, 
Having never used DriveType before that has led me to start reading on it so I can fully understand your example. 
Once again thanks for pointing me in the right direction.